# C# Apply Colour to specific word

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, export

I'm using Microsoft.Interop.Word in WinForms to create a word document,

what i'm looking to do is change the specific colour of a word/words in my output document, so for example:

```
para5b.Range.Text = "my phone number is <different colour phone number here>";
```

i currently just have the entire thing set to:

```
para5b.Range.Font.Color = WdColor.wdColorBlack;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with

```
para5b.Range.Words[indexOfYourWord].Font.Color = yourDesiredColor;
```

Comment: perfect, exactly what i was looking for.